# Autonomous Database in the Oracle Cloud; Can I run R Scripts Natively Like with Oracle Enterprise?

Tags: r, oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

In the past few months Oracle has included an Autonomous Container Database option in the Cloud.  I was wondering if it allows for setup and configuration of running R scripts in the Db Engine like how once could previously with Oracle Enterprise Database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This is possible since late August 2022: https://blogs.oracle.com/post/oracle-machine-learning-for-r-now-available-for-oracle-autonomous-database